# Copying an array to another array as reversed and display in Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, irvine32

I am trying to copy an array to another array, but the order of elements should be reversed and displayed. My program file compiles but does not run and causes a Windows stop error each time (Windows dialog box).
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please advise.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
sarray DWORD 500h, 400h, 300h, 200h, 100h
darray DWORD 5 DUP(?)

.code
main PROC

    mov eax, 0
    mov esi, OFFSET sarray ;move first element address to esi
    mov edi, OFFSET darray + SIZEOF darray - TYPE darray  ;move last element address to edi
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF sarray  ;sets the counter in the reverseLoop

  reverseLoop:
    mov eax,sarray[esi]     ;move 1st sarray element to eax
    mov darray[edi],eax     ;move 1st sarray element as last element on darray
    call WriteInt
    call Crlf
    add esi, TYPE sarray
    sub edi, TYPE darray
    call WriteInt
    loop reverseLoop

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

**Edit**: My problem was that `esi` and `edi` had the address already added (`OFFSET sarray`) but in the loop I added the start again (`mov eax, sarray[esi]`).

After the fix, I had to add another loop to print the second *darray* (new one)

Comment: Do you have a condition to exit your loop?

Comment: The `loop` instruction on x86 decrements `ecx` as a counter and exits if it goes to zero. So, it's not infinite.

Comment: "My program file stops to work after the compile." is not a good error description, please specify exactly what happens. Also, use a debugger.

Comment: Your problem is that you load `esi` and `edi` with the address already (you added `OFFSET sarray`) but in the loop you add the start again (`mov eax,sarray[esi] `). Delete it from one of the places.

Comment: Thank you for the support, the code is running now without error. But this time I see the result as not reversed .

Comment: Sure, you are printing it in the same loop that you use to reverse it, so it's in the original order. To print the reversed one, you need a separate loop to print it. Or, process the array from back to front.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that `esi` and `edi` with the address already added `OFFSET sarray`, but in the loop I added the start again (`mov eax, sarray[esi]`).

After fixing this, I also had to add another loop to print the second array (the reversed one).

Here is the working code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
sarray DWORD 500h, 400h, 300h, 200h, 100h
darray DWORD 5 DUP(?)

.code
main PROC

    mov esi, OFFSET sarray                                ;move first element address to esi
    mov edi, OFFSET darray + SIZEOF darray - TYPE darray  ;move last element address to edi
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF sarray                              ;sets the counter in the reverseLoop

reverseLoop:
    mov eax,[esi]       ;move 1st sarray element to eax
    mov [edi],eax       ;move 1st sarray element as last element to the darray  
    add esi, TYPE sarray
    sub edi, TYPE darray
    loop reverseLoop
    call clrscr

    mov esi, OFFSET darray
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF darray
    mov ebx, 0

printerLoop:
    mov eax,[esi]
    call WriteHex           
    call Crlf
    add esi, TYPE darray
    loop printerLoop

    call Crlf

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: To make this a better answer (one that I would upvote), please [edit] it to include (at the top) a brief description of what was wrong with your original code and how you changed it. Jester basically told you this already in the comments, so it's great that you were able to take the hints and turn it into real code, but ideally, we'd like that information to be in the answer itself.

Comment: Edited.Thank you for the advise